# Is there a "local" timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp, pytz

I can convert from an UTC timestamp e.g. 1417392000 to a local datetime object including daylight saving time, but when I try and convert the local datetime object to a "local timestamp" then I get the same UTC timestamp as before.

Am I thinking in circles and they are the same? I was supposed to save "local timestamp" from incoming UTC timestamp.

This is my code

```
    print("UTC timestamp %d" % hour[0])
    day = self.get_day(hour)
    month = self.get_month(hour)
    year = self.get_year(hour)
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm')
    utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(hour[0])).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    print("UTC datetime %s" % utc_dt)
    dt = tz.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(tz))
    print("STO datetime %s" % dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
    print("STO ts %d" % int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple())))
    print("STO timestamp %d" % utc_dt.astimezone(tz).timestamp())
    day = int(dt.strftime('%d'))
    month = int(dt.strftime('%m'))
    year = int(dt.strftime('%Y'))
```

Output

```
UTC timestamp 1417395600
UTC datetime 2014-12-01 01:00:00+00:00
STO datetime 2014-12-01 02:00:00 CET+0100
STO ts 1417395600
STO timestamp 1417395600
```

All "timestamps" (i.e. integer representations of the time) are the same. Is it possible to make a "local timestamp" ? The data type is supposed to be a timestamp that is a number and in local time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for
>   describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that
>   have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC),
>   Thursday, 1 January 1970

So regardless of what timezone you're on, the epoch will always be calculated in the UTC timezone.

For display purposes, you can convert the timestamp to a local time, but as otherwise the internal representation of the epoch will always be in the UTC timezone

Answer (score 1):

## Formal timestamps

The Unix [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) typically refers to the number of seconds since the epoch in UTC.  This value is invariant to timezone.  It allows global event ordering but loses timezone information.

## Preserving timezone

To preserve timezone information, a standardized format is [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), *Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps*.  This is just a standardized formatting that encodes date+time+timezone. Some examples:

```
1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z
1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00
1990-12-31T23:59:60Z
1990-12-31T15:59:60-08:00
```

## Normalizing for timezone without preservation of timezone

However, it may depend on your requirements.  I once wanted to record some events relative to local-time-of-day and did not mind losing timezone information.  I normalized the timestamp with respect to 1970-01-01T00:00:00 in the local timezone.  I am a little sheepish about this now as I think it may too easily cause confusion.

```
import time

# Number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00+LTZ (current timezone).
# unix timestamp - timezone offset in seconds
timestamp_localized = time.time() - time.mktime(time.gmtime(0))
```

However this syntax can be simplified, perhaps at the loss of clarity, by noticing that Python has some localtime and UTC specific functions.

```
import time
import calendar

# Number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00+LTZ (current timezone).
# Interpret local date and time as if it were UTC
timestamp_localized = calendar.timegm(time.localtime())
```

The difference between these two is that calendar conversion truncates to the second while the difference calculation includes a fractional second.